# Why is Call Browser disabled in my VS2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to understand a C++ DLL I didn't write, and it would be really useful to see the function call hierarchy.

But when I right click on a function name, and select Call Browser, all the menu items are disabled.

I've looked through all the project and solutions settings, and deleted .ncb file and Debug and Release dirs, but nothing works.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

(Running on Windows XP, VS2008 SP1)

Answer (score 1):

After posting my question, I restarted VS, and now Call Browser is working.

I guess deleting either the .ncb or the build directories fixed it, but a VS restart is also required.

(Browsing and Intellisense seems extremely fragile for C++, compared to C#. My Intellisense also broke a couple of weeks ago).